# React hook cleanup when refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an app built in React using hooks that when closed needs to notify the server. I tried doing it using the following approach:

```
function onUnload() {

        if (roomID !== "")
            endGame(roomID, dispatch);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        return onUnload;
    },[])
```

Here, `endGame` is a function that performs a HTTP request to the backend. But when refreshing the page to emulate a user closing the app, the request never reaches the server, meaning that the cleanup function doesn't get executed. Any ideas on what is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Refreshing the page is not same as component unmount. When you refresh the page, the React state is reset as React solely works on the current client session and refresh is equivalent to resetting it. What you are lloking for might be the `onunload` event. Try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return onUnload();
};
```

Comment: I've already tried with window.addEventListener('beforeunload',()=>{...}) but it didn't work. Using the setter directly is any different?

Comment: @AdrianPascu it looks as though you're returning the function object rather than just doing the unload action.